# Как получить элемент-родитель?

Tags: javascript, dom

Т.е. в

```
<section>
   <div id="elem">
   </div>
</section>
```

от `document.getElementById('elem')` надо получить тот `<section>`.

**p.s.**
`document.getElementById('elem').parrentNode` не работает (возвращает `undefined`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Будьте внимательны:

```
document.getElementById('elem').parentNode // с одной "r"
```